# Enter data horizontally in Excel from SQL query

Tags: excel, vba

Currently the following SQL query in Excel VBA shows the count data vertically

So the column header is in A1 and the count result is in B1

```
Const sqlconnection = "Provider=visoledb;"

Dim conn As New Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = sqlconnection
    conn.Open

Dim rs As Recordset
Dim r1 As String
    r1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user"

Set rs = conn.Execute(r1)
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rs, Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .Refresh
End With

rs.close
```

Is it possible to have it show the header text in A1 and the count value in A2?
So it shows vertically across the cells in a single row left to right

Comment: Perhaps edit your question, as it doesn't read correctly. Data presented vertically would be "A1", "A2", etc. Data presented horizontally would be "A1", "B1", etc. BTW, I'm not aware of a single line of code that would transpose a `Recordset`.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your code and got it working, but I only had a local database to test it on so I used DAO- this wont work for you if you only have a connection string unfortunately, but if you have the full filepath of the DB then you can use this code directly, if not then hopefully the syntax helps you figure out the missing step in your OCDB code, they are very similar.

Second, I think there is something wrong with your SQL Query String- I don't think it does what you think it does. When you say you want the data 'across the cells in a single row left to right' but a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query is only going to return 1 field so you are only going to have 1 column...

Anyways, here is the code doing what you want it to- hopefully once you have tinkered with the SQL String you'll have all the pieces you need to get it working:

```
Public Sub sampleCode()
    Dim targetWS As Worksheet
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim SQLString As String
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set targetWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set db = Access.DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase("C:\DB File.accdb")
    SQLString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [user]"

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQLString)
    rs.MoveLast
    rs.MoveFirst
    With targetWS.QueryTables
        .Add Connection:=rs, Destination:=Range("A1")
        .Item(1).Refresh
    End With

    db.Close
End Sub
```

Hope this helps,
TheSilkCode

Comment: Thank you anyway. I only have the connection string as it is pulling the data from a PG database into Excel using the visoledb driver. I can move the fields around in VBA, but I just wondered if it could be achieved directly so that the single count value sits beside the field description instead of under.